# Reset closure variables for unit testing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following module in Javascript

```js
var module = (function (){
  var cache = {};
  return {
    postMessage: function (msg){
      if(!cache[msg]){
        cache[msg] = true;
        console.log(msg);
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

When I write unit tests in Jasmine for this module I would like to have a clean module with an empty cache variable at the beginning of each test. I can't find a solution for this problem except for a helper function that clears the cache and that is publicly available.

Is there a way to clear closure variables for unit testing? I don't need a solution for production code, because in case I would like to clear in production I would have such a helper function anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to reset the cache in your case. What you have here is a Singleton with a private state, so your lost, cause you can't reset the state and you cant create a new instance of `module` in your test.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. I will just add the reset method as it might come in handy in production as well.

Comment: I was also looking for answer is it possible to reset closure value.